# How to Retrieve (Get) Response Headers (Accept-Language) Without Using the Internet?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb6, http-headers, httprequest

I was hoping to get the "Accept-Language" header that a users Internet Explorer browser sends to web pages (servers). I wanted to do this without connecting to a web page, but just through some .dll COM call or Windows API or some other method that would give me this information without connecting to the internet. I'l looking for the most reliable method which spans Window 2000 - Windows 8.1.

I am open to getting this by making a web request but would prefer to do it without, ie: by making an API call or doing it the real way (whatever that is). When I searched the internet/google, people would only show code examples that involve connecting to some server etc... and I couldn't find the local (non-internet) method of doing this.

Anyone know? I am using VB6 (Visual Basic 6.0) but can take code examples in VB.NET or C# as they are easy to translate for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accept language is stored in registry([Help: How to change the default language for Internet Explorer using C# code?](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/445603-help-how-change-default-language-internet-explorer-using-c-code)):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\International
 REG_SZ: AcceptLanguage

 example en-gb,ar-eg;q=0.5
```

In vb.net it is simple( [How to: Read a Value from a Registry Key in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz88758e.aspx))

```
Dim readValue = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\International",
 "AcceptLanguage",Nothing)
```

In vb6 is necessary to use API see: [Microsoft:How To Use the Registry API to Save and Retrieve Setting](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/145679)

Comment: Ah, you're a friggen champion man, thank you so much. You just made my day and made me feel much better about my options for writing this bit of code. Up voted & Accepted as Answer :).